# Registering Android activity lifecycle not being triggered

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I am working on an Android app and I am trying to register the activity lifecycle call back.

In my launcher activity (Agreement.java) in the `onCreate` method I have the following:

```
this.getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new LoginManager());
```

This activity does a check if the agreement has been agreed, and if so immediately finishes and calls LoginActivity.java but the toast notification I have in my activity call back class doesn't show and neither do my logcat messages so it doesn't look like its getting fired.

Below is the LoginManager class which implements the activity call backs

```
public class LoginManager extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    private final String TAG = "LoginManager";
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Activity Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity Created");
        long currentEpochTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000l;
        Log.d(TAG, "Current Epoch: " + currentEpochTime);
        CommonTasks commonTasks = new CommonTasks(activity);
        SharedPreferences settings = commonTasks.getAppsSharedPreferences();

        long timeDifference = currentEpochTime - settings.getLong(Defines.SharedPreferenceSettings.LAST_ACTIVE_EPOCH, 0);
        Log.d(TAG, "Time Difference: " + timeDifference);
        if (timeDifference >= 120) //2 Minutes
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Logging out");
            //Over 2 minutes so we need to logout
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Not Logging Out");
            //No need to logout, save the current time
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putLong(Defines.SharedPreferenceSettings.LAST_ACTIVE_EPOCH, currentEpochTime);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

So just to reiterate, the agreement class registers the lifecycle callback (LoginManager) instantly closes and shows LoginActivity but the toast and logcat isn't triggered.

Comment: So commenting out everything except the toast and log produces nothing?

Comment: So you are forcibly taking the users back to the Login screen when they start a new activity after 2 minutes? This doesn't stop someone from staying in an Activity for longer than 2 minutes...

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't need to worry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `LoginManager` class add

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }
```

And remove

```
this.getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new LoginManager());
```

from `Agreement.java`

Answer (score 1):

You are registering the callback too late. The activity is already created so the callback is not invoked. Have you tried registering during the onCreate of Application rather than Activity? You can define your own Application class and indicate that in the manifest by specifying the application name attribute as your custom class.

Comment: "You can define your own Application class " -- Yes, clearly that was already done as per `LoginManager extends Application`

Comment: But you are instantiating LoginManager. Android is not creating your Application object. The normal flow is that an Application object or its custom subclass is instantiated by the operating system when you launch the app.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the person who wrote the code is instantiating the LoginManager object manually and that's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set class name of your application class in manifest? Like this:

```
<application
android:name=".LoginManager"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Also, why don't you put

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
```

inside onCreate method of your LoginManager?